# How to mount a Truecrypt container with a timeout from the command line?

Tags: command-line, mount, timeout, unmounting, truecrypt

I'm mounting a truecrypt container via the command line (i.e. `truecrypt file dir`). Is there any way to have truecrypt automatically unmount the container after a given amount of inactivity in `dir`?

Comment: That's a job for an automounter. Last time I used one on Linux, they kind of sucked, but I think they've improved in the last decade.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for pointing it out, I'll try and find one for this

Comment: Can `truecrypt` be mounted with the `mount` command?

Comment: Could you perhaps use something similar to @ultrasawblade's script and leverage `lsof` (or possibly /proc/*/fd or somesuch; lsof gets its data from *somewhere*...)? It wouldn't be perfect (very fast accesses would go uncaught, and it would cause a bit of CPU hammering), but I'm guessing it's either something like that, or access notifies (which at the very least means write a system application, not a script).

Answer (score 1):

Truecrypt can't do this but something like the following would accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
#!/bin/bash
TIMEOUT_PERIOD_IN_MINUTES=60

cd /
sleep ${TIMEOUT_PERIOD_IN_MINUTES}m
echo "$0: Proceeding with dismount in 5 minutes." > /dev/console
# or something else to notify user that the volume will be unmounted
sleep 4.5m
echo "$0: Proceeding with dismount in 30 seconds." > /dev/console
sleep 30s
sync; truecrypt $@
```

The `cd /` would be to ensure that the current directory is never within the mounted truecrypt volume, just in case you invoked it under different circumstances.

Save this somewhere, `chmod +x` it, and call it something like `truecrypt-auto-dismount`, and then

`truecrypt {mount-options}; truecrypt-auto-dismount {dismount-options}`

I would definitely incorporate some type of notification so you have a chance to close open files.  Of course you could get rather elaborate and try to incorporate a loop that kills with SIGTERM (and then does SIGKILL if it doesn't respond in a timeframe) all processes listed by `lsof | grep /mnt/your-truecrypt-volume` if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, that's a general timeout, but I'm looking for a possiblity to have the timer reset whenever the mounted `dir` is accessed again. And http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=background-task suggest that this is possible when using the GUI (which I can't)